# appcelerator alloy pass arguments

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am trying to figure out how to pass an argument between views in alloy. I will have a have nav group which will have multiple tables, so it maybe 3 to 5 levels deep.

I can pass arguments from the controller to the view but I want to pass information (ids of categories) from the view to the next table when it is clicked.

I am not sure how to do this in alloy, I always get undefined errors when trying to access the variable. Below is my current setup.

In my views I have: index.xml, master.xml, row.xml, detail.xml, subDetail.xml

**Index.xml**

```
<Alloy>

    <Window id="index">
        <NavigationGroup id="navgroup">
            <Require src="master" id="master"/>
        </NavigationGroup>
    </Window>


</Alloy>
```

**Here is my index.js**

```
Alloy.Globals.navgroup = $.navgroup;    


$.master.on('detail', function(e) {
    // get the detail controller and window references
    var controller = Alloy.createController('detail');
    var win = controller.getView();



    // open the detail windows 
    $.navgroup.open(win);
    /*
    if (OS_IOS && Alloy.isHandheld) {
        Alloy.Globals.navgroup.open(win);   
    } else if (OS_ANDROID) {
        win.open();
    }*/
});




$.index.open();
```

**master.xml**

```
<Alloy>

    <Window title="Categories">
        <TableView id="table" onClick="openDetail">


        </TableView>
    </Window>


</Alloy>
```

**master.js**

```
function openDetail(e) {
$.trigger('detail', e);
}


var data = [];

var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({ 

                     onerror: function(e){ 

                           Ti.API.debug(e.error); 

                           alert('There was an error during the connection'); 

                     }, 

                  timeout:1000, 

              });                      

              //Here you have to change it for your local ip 


              sendit.open('GET', 'http://url.com/json.php?showCats=1');

              sendit.send(); 

              //Function to be called upon a successful response 

              sendit.onload = function(){ 

                     var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 

                     //var json = json.todo; 

                     //if the database is empty show an alert 

                     if(json.length == 0){ 
                        $.table.headerTitle = "The database row is empty"; 
                     }                      

                     //Emptying the data to refresh the view 



                     //Insert the JSON data to the table view


                    for ( var i=0; i<json.length; i++){ 


                        data.push(Alloy.createController('row', {                           
                            name: json[i].CatName,
                            catID: json[i].CatID

                        }).getView());

                        //data.push(row);

                        Ti.API.info(json[i].CatName);
                        Ti.API.info(json[i].CatID);


                    }                                     

                    $.table.setData(data);                      
               };
```

**row.xml**

```
<Alloy>
<TableViewRow>
<Label id="name"/>
<Label id="catID"/>
</TableViewRow>
</Alloy>
```

**row.js**

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};


$.row.fighterName = $.name.text = args.name;
$.catID.text = args.catID;
```

**detail.xml**

```
    <Alloy>

<Window title="Sub Categories">
<TableView id="subtable" onClick="openSubDetail">
</TableView>

</Window>
</Alloy>
```

**detail.js**

```
function openSubDetail(e) {
$.trigger('subDetail', e);


}


var data = [];



var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({ 

                     onerror: function(e){ 

                           Ti.API.debug(e.error); 

                           alert('There was an error during the connection'); 

                     }, 

                  timeout:1000, 

              });                      

              //Here you have to change it for your local ip 



              Ti.API.info('Cat id');
              Ti.API.info(catID);
              Ti.API.info('data Value:'+ $.detail.catID );


              sendit.open('GET', 'http://url.com/mobile/includes/json.php?catID=12');

              sendit.send(); 

              //Function to be called upon a successful response 

              sendit.onload = function(){ 

                     var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 

                     //var json = json.todo; 

                     //if the database is empty show an alert 

                     if(json.length == 0){ 
                        $.table.headerTitle = "The database row is empty"; 
                     }                      

                     //Emptying the data to refresh the view 



                     //Insert the JSON data to the table view


                    for ( var i=0; i<json.length; i++){ 


                        data.push(Alloy.createController('subDetail', {                         
                            name: json[i].SubcatName,
                            catID: json[i].CatID

                        }).getView());

                        //data.push(row);
                        Ti.API.info('Second Level');
                        Ti.API.info(json[i].SubcatName);

                    }                                     

                    $.subtable.setData(data);                      
               };
```

Comment: i do not see the stub code for where you want to pass the data? I am assuming you want to track a click event on a row and then open a new window passing the information in?

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure where to pass it. I want to pass from row to detail but I am not sure how to pass it. I tried argument 0 but it does not seem to work. I tried looking at fugitive also but did not see how it was passed. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the row click event create a new controller and pass in the object as a parameter to the controller. This way when the window is opened in the controller, the controller has the data.

it is the same as you have done when creating the `subDetail` row

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried that when I do it I get "subDetail" as undefined. I am still getting an error but I know the way you suggested is right. I tried moving all of details.js into row.js. Is that what you had in mind or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you need to post your code in a gist so someone can take a look and see what your problem is

Comment: I created a gist here. I took the detail.js code and put in the row.js but I can set $.subtable.setData, it is undefined.... any thoughts? How can $.subtable exist? https://gist.github.com/digitalbart/6bcce1e49d4eaef9d021